# I would like to make an invice in java using netbeans 8

Tags: java, report

My question is this that i want to make an invice or we can say bill for our customer , so that now i want to make an invice that has a special style it mean customer logos,address 
like this and then i want to print it directly by printer devices so plz can anyone help  me .
I use netbeas 8 IDE .

Comment: Hire some freelancers for your job we do modifications to error code not build whole code.Nice idea any way.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a report, using iReport, and send data to fill it. All data can be organized in a model report, like images, grid (sub-report) with monetary values, bar-codes, etc...

http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-designer-tutorials-help

Comment: iReport has been replaced by Jasper Studio

Comment: nowadays in my work we are using "Pentaho report designer", didn't knew it @MadProgrammer. thanks